# GNU set heatmap axis limits around a dynamically computed point

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I'm plotting a heatmap in gnuplot from a text file that is in matrix format:

```
z11 z12 z13
z21 z22 z23
z31 z32 z33
```

and so forth, using the following command (not including axis labelling, etc, for brevity):

```
plot '~/some_text_file.txt' matrix notitle with image
```

The matrix is quite large, in excess of 50 000 elements in the majority of cases, and it's mostly due to the size of my y-dimension (#rows). I would like to know if there's a way to change the limits in the y-dimension for a set number of values around a maximum, while keeping the x and z dimensions the same. E.g. if a maximum in the matrix is at [4000, 33], I want my y range to be centred at 4000 +- let's say 20% of length of the y-dimension.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want gnuplot to find the maximum, or would you be able to find it with another program/script?

Comment: Whichever will be simpler, I could add a routine to my program to compute the maximum, but how can I use that value in gnuplot?

Comment: The easiest way would be to (manually) set variables in your script to specify the y-center and y range: `MINDEX=4000; RANGE=50; set yrange [MINDEX-RANGE:MINDEX+RANGE]`

Comment: That would be the easiest yeah, but the max index is going to change every time that I plot the data.

Answer (score 2):

---

**Edit:**

The solution below is basically the correct idea, however it works in my example but not in general because a bug in how gnuplot uses the `stats` command with matrix files. See the comments after the answer for further info.

---

You can do this using `stats` to get the indices that correspond to the maximum value dynamically.

Consider the following file which I named `data`:

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 5 3 4
0 1 2 3 4
```

If I run `stats`I get:

```
gnuplot> stats "data" matrix

* FILE: 
  Records:      25
  Out of range:  0
  Invalid:       0
  Blank:         0
  Data Blocks:   1

* MATRIX: [5 X 5] 
  Mean:          2.1200
  Std Dev:       1.5315
  Sum:          53.0000
  Sum Sq.:     171.0000

  Minimum:       0.0000 [ 0 0 ]
  Maximum:       5.0000 [ 3 2 ]
  COG:           2.9434      2.0566
```

The maximum value is in position `[ 3 2 ]` meaning row 3+1 and column 2+1 (in gnuplot the first row/column would be number 0). After running `stats` some variables are created automatically (`help stats` for more info), with `STATS_index_max_x` and `STATS_index_max_y` among them, which store the position of the maximum:

```
gnuplot> print STATS_index_max_x
3.0
gnuplot> print STATS_index_max_y
2.0
```

Which you can use to automatically set the ranges. Now, because `STATS_index_max_x` actually gives you the y (instead of x) position, you'll need to be careful. The total number of rows to obtain the range can be obtained with a system call (there might be a better built-in function, which I do not know):

```
gnuplot> range = system("awk 'END{print NR}' data")
gnuplot> print range
5
```

So basically you'll do:

```
stats "data" matrix
range = system("awk 'END{print NR}' data")
range_center = STATS_index_max_x
d = 0.2 * range
set yrange [range_center - d : range_center + d]
```

which will center the `yrange` at the position of your maximum value and will stretch it by +-20% of its total range.

The result of `plot "data" matrix w image` is now

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: I had also though about this, but the indices computed by gnuplot are wrong. In your case it works (although with x and y being exchanged), because the matrix you have is symmetric. See the bug report [#1501 Dimensions for `stats matrix` are exchanged.](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1501/). Nevertheless a good idea, +1 :)

Comment: @Christoph Yes, you're right! I've put a warning at the beginning of the answer. Maybe if (when) they fix the bug this answer can then be useful.